# Use HEIC (application/octet-strem) base64 in <img src="data:image/png;base64,..."

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a HEIC file which I am receiving as a response

```
{
   content: <entire base64 content>,
   filename: "File.heic",
   type: "application/octet-stream"
}
```

need to display this as a image on the browser.
I have tried with

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,..."
```

or

```
<img src="data:application/octet-stream;base64,..."
```

but it's not rendering. How to achieve this? Do I need to convert this to image/png base64? How do I do that? I am using ReactJS btw

Comment: did you solve the issue you were facing?